# UIView draw in subview

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

Is it possible for a container UIView to draw in a child UIView? If so, how do I obtain the child's cgcontext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, add an accessor to the clild view's context.

Just because it is possible doesn't mean that this is recommended. In fact it is a really bad idea. A better is to ask the subview to change the way it is drawing. Set an accessor for an instance variable, or set a new state that will change the drawing.

Comment: Another alternative: Add to the child view a custom subview that contains the content you wish displayed.

Comment: Agreed, now that I've looked into the subject a little more, that it is a bad idea. I was used to Flash's mySprite.myShape.myOtherShape.graphics.drawRect(); type methods and was looking for something similar. Quartz is a little too low level for that. CoreAnimation layers do have some of this functionality tho I guess.